# How to create a seekable stream of bytedata from a local video file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a local video file in phone. I am using flutter. I want to access the file as a stream of bytedata and should be able to seek to a position just like in RandomAccessFile in flutter. How to do that in flutter ?

Comment: If you do a google search regarding this you will find ton of resources that you can get help from. Did you try something? If so, is there any problem with your approach?

Comment: Actually i am unable to find any resources that help me create a seekable stream. I am able to use RandomAccessFile in dart, but issue is, i want to just open the local file as stream and that shouldn't block the UI. Because my file is very large. I just want to use it as a stream and should be able to seek to a desired position in bytes. That is currently i am unable to do in flutter.